# Circle in $\mathbb{C}$ exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show that if a circle has its center in the origin and the radius is $2$, then every point $z$ of that circle has the property that $\left|z^{4}-4z^{2}+3\right|\geq3$.

I know that the circle $C=\left\{ z:\left|z-0\right|=\left|z\right|=2\right\}$ So the norm of $z$ is $2$ but I don't know how to take that and connect it to the inequality. 
I'm kind of a newbie in this area so any idea would be appreciated.

My answer: $$\left|z^{4}-4z^{2}+3\right|=\left|\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(z^{2}-3\right)\right|=\left|z^{2}-1\right|\left|z^{2}-3\right|\geq\left|\left|z^{2}\right|-\left|1\right|\right|\left|\left|z^{2}\right|-\left|3\right|\right|=\left|\left|z\right|^{2}-1\right|\left|\left|z\right|^{2}-3\right|=\left|4-1\right|\left|1\right|=3$$

I've used the reverse triangle inequality, and the fact that $\left|z\right|=2\Rightarrow\left|z\right|^{2}=4$

Comment: Note:  technically, $C$ is a circle, and its length is called circumference.  (In everyday use, the term ["circle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) may refer to the circle and its interior, but technically the circle is only the boundary, and the whole figure is called a disc.  Informally, ["circumference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference) may also refer to the edge itself rather than to the length of the edge.)

Comment: @Jack Talion Well done! (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$z^{4}-4z^{2}+3=(z^2-1)(z^2-3)$$
and recall the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality): for all $u,v\in\mathbb{C}$, $|u-v|\geq ||u|-|v||$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I did it, soon I will post my answer. Thank you so much!